# global, buffer and process are undefined in ionic 4 angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic4, angular8

I'm trying to use an external js npm library in an Angular 8 ionic 4 app and I received

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: global is not defined
```

I tried to solve this problem by inserting in polyfill.ts the following code:

```
(window as any).global = window;
 import * as buffer from 'buffer';
 window['buffer'] = buffer;
 import * as process from 'process';
 window['process'] = process;
```

When I try to run the ionic app with "ionic serve" I receive a run time error with:

```
index.js:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/polyfills.ts (polyfills.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object.1 (zone-flags.ts:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at polyfills.js:1
...
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: global is not defined
ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/stream-http/lib/capability.js (capability.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object../node_modules/stream-http/lib/request.js (request.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object../node_modules/stream-http/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object../node_modules/rss-parser/lib/parser.js (parser.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object../node_modules/rss-parser/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original Answer**

Angular is a Framework for client side. The runtime target is the browser. You cannot use libraries like `process` there, since those are only available when running a nodejs process.

You most likely want to split your application into a client and a server side.

**Solution for rss-parser**

As you mentioned in your comment, the library in question is `rss-parser`. As described [in this issue](https://github.com/rbren/rss-parser/issues/120), `rss-parser` is currently not working correctly with angular when using a bundler. Most likely due to [not having ES Module support](https://github.com/rbren/rss-parser/issues/96).

The solution is to use the prebundled version that gets shipped with the library. To do that, add the prepackaged version to your `angular.json`, into the `script` array in your `architects` `build` section. `RSSReader` is now available globally, in your `window` object and can be used like this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// This tells TypeScript that you know this will be available globally during runtime.
// Unfortunately, RSSParser has no TS Declarations, so you have to use any or make a more concrete type yourself
declare const RSSParser:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})   
export class AppComponent  {
  title:string = '';
  items:Array<any> = []; 

  constructor() {
    const CORS_PROXY = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" 
    let parser = new RSSParser(); 
    parser.parseURL(CORS_PROXY + 'https://www.reddit.com/.rss', (err, feed) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(feed);
      this.title = feed.title;
      this.items = feed.items;
    })
  }
}
```

Here is [a working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-omu1im).

Comment: The library I need to use is rss-parser, I need to define buffer because also buffer is undefined.

Comment: @Alessandra Updated my answer with a working example and an explanation.